# Performance Counters in Windbg Crash Dump

Tags: windows, debugging, crash, windbg, performancecounter

Is it possible to see thread performance counters in dump of native c++ application in windbg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it not possible to see the values of the counters because are not stored in the c++ application address space. All you may extract from the dump are the thread ids, user time, kernel time and elapsed time (see the !runaway command).